# Coldfusion - PayPal express checkout returns Invalid Transaction when using lightbox

Tags: jquery, paypal, coldfusion

I am writing custom code for a shopping cart that must be completed using ColdFusion. (I am not allowed to switch out to anything else). I am attempting to implement PayPal express checkout using a lightbox for customer ease of use, but have been running into nothing but frustration with the process.

There are not many Coldfusion examples out there that are easy to understand; however, after very long searching I have managed to track down enough code to put together what seems to mostly work. I have also been through the PayPal developers site and their code more times than I can remember and they seem to assume you don't need any full coding examples.

Here is what I have gotten to partially work using the live payment url. It seems to work fine using sandbox but fails when I switch to a live environment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js"></script> 


<cfset application.pp.username = "--username--"/>
<cfset application.pp.password = "--password--"/>
<cfset application.pp.signature = "--signature-"/>
<cfset application.pp.id = "--application.id--"/>
<cfset application.pp.version = "114.0"/>

<cfscript>
  stDetails = structNew();
  stDetails.cartTotal = 1.00;
  stDetails.invoiceno = 3456;
</cfscript>

<cfhttp url="https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp" method="post">
    <!--- auth --->
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="USER" value="#application.pp.username#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PWD" value="#application.pp.password#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="SIGNATURE" value="#application.pp.signature#" />
    <!--- order info --->
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="VERSION" value="#application.pp.version#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="LOCALE" value="AU" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="#stDetails.cartTotal#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM" value="#stDetails.invoiceno#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" value="AUD" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC" value="your products" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="returnURL" value="http://#cgi.server_name#/index.cfm?event=shop-cart-process" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="cancelURL" value="http://#cgi.server_name#/index.cfm?event=shop-cart-process" />
</cfhttp>

<body>

<cfoutput>

<cfset myDocument = trim(cfhttp.fileContent)>
#myDocument#<br>

<cfset payPalStruct = structNew()>
<cfloop list="#cfhttp.fileContent#" index="elem" delimiters ="&">
    <cfset payPalStruct[listFirst(elem,'=')] = URLDecode(listLast(elem,'=')) />
</cfloop>

#StructFind(payPalStruct,"token")#<br />


<cfdump var="#payPalStruct#">


http://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=#StructFind(payPalStruct,"token")#

<form action="http://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=#StructFind(payPalStruct,"token")#" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
<label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
<input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="#StructFind(payPalStruct,"token")#">  
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>

</body>

</cfoutput>
```

I am getting a token returned just fine using cfhttp and our credentials. That part works like a champ and outputs the results to the page just fine. When I go to hit the PayPal button, the lightbox window pops up but returns

> This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website
>   and try again.

Nothing I have done has changed this error. I have scoured the internet looking for any type of answer and usually it turns out the answer that is usually provided is that the pay key is not being returned or to just refer to the PayPal SDK. In this case the pay key/token is being returned just fine and things seems to fail upon execution of the lightbox itself when it is being populated by PayPal.

If anyone has any insight into this problem or working Coldfusion code that deals with express/adaptive payments, that would be incredibly helpful. There just does not seem to be an easy tutorial out there anywhere for ColdFusion integration with the PayPal SDK.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm pondering this.  Because I use paypal and coldfusion and sometimes goofy things happen (at first).  I bet it is something simple. Question.  What happens if you take the button out of the lightbox and I am assuming all the other code you need to process your payment that could be inside the lightbox. So you just have a linear event without the lightbox interference?

Comment: I am with you; however, there still has to be some way to trigger the PayPal login. I have tried it using the mini-browser code instead of lightbox and the same thing happens. Unfortunately, I know of no way to implement the PayPal login directly on my page without calling the API as in their examples.